# How to sum up to 4 (or more) columns in a query based on checkboxes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Basically I have 4 checkboxes and I want to sum up to 4 columns based on those, with the formula query:

It's a bit ugly what I di and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it, especially if I want to add more checkboxes or even a multiplier to those sums. Thanks in advance for your reply.

example:

```
IF(M4,
    IF(M5,
        IF(M6,
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) 'Q1-4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(D)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(D)) 'Q1-3'", 1)),
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(C) + SUM(E)) 'Q1 Q2 Q4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(C)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(C)) 'Q1 Q2'", 1))),
        IF(M6,
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) 'Q1 Q3 Q4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(D)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(D)) 'Q1 Q3'", 1)),
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B) + SUM(E)) 'Q1 Q4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(B)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(B)) 'Q1'", 1)))),
    IF(M5,
        IF(M6,
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(C) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(C) + SUM(D) + SUM(E)) 'Q2-4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(C) + SUM(D)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(C) + SUM(D)) 'Q2 Q3'", 1)),
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(C) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(C) + SUM(E)) 'Q2 Q4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(C)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(C)) 'Q2'", 1))),
        IF(M6,
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(D) + SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(D) + SUM(E)) 'Q3 Q4'", 1),
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(D)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(D)) 'Q3'", 1)),
            IF(M7,
                query(A3:E10,"Select A, (SUM(E)) where A is not null group by A label (SUM(E)) 'Q4'", 1)))))
```

here is a link to a sample sheet: [Link to a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6WYH8syfete_F93tWHKwBGUi-imAQquD16N0LBOeJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey, can share some sample data ? (dummy sheet, etc;.)

Comment: Sure here's a link (it is for a game and what need to be farmed) [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6WYH8syfete_F93tWHKwBGUi-imAQquD16N0LBOeJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a way to achieve this.

The problem with your formula is that your condition is outside the query.
Right now it's something like this :

```
10 Conditions -> 10 Querys -> 1 SQL statements for each query
```

What I can propose is this :

```
1 Query -> 10 conditions -> 1 SQL statement for each conditions
```

First, I added some valuable information inside an array with some "*settings*"

[image]

Then i tried to construct a sql statement when only one box is `true` :

```
="SELECT "&C1&", (SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")) 
where "&C1&" is not null AND ("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&") > 0 
group by "&C1&" 
label (SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")) '"&FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5)&"'"
```

Output is this 
[image: enter preformatted text here]

Then when multiples boxes are checked :

```
=ArrayFormula(
   "SELECT G, ("&TEXTJOIN("+",true,ArrayFormula("SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")"))&") 
     Where G is not null AND ("&TEXTJOIN(" + ",true,ArrayFormula(FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)))&") > 0 
    group by G 
    label ("&TEXTJOIN("+",true,ArrayFormula("SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")"))&") 'Q"&textjoin("-",true,FILTER(arrayformula(row(A1:A4)),A2:A5))&"'"
)
```

Now the final `query` is :

```
=query(
    Blacksmithing!G3:K10,
    ArrayFormula(
        "SELECT G, ("&TEXTJOIN("+",true,ArrayFormula("SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")"))&") 
        where G is not null AND ("&TEXTJOIN(" + ",true,ArrayFormula(FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)))&") > 0 
group by G 
        label ("&TEXTJOIN("+",true,ArrayFormula("SUM("&FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5)&")"))&") 'Q"&textjoin("-",true,FILTER(arrayformula(row(A1:A4)),A2:A5))&"'")
    )
```

[Working example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lg3dgvlnW-2AXBpijEBRG30fqUObzdVgVuijOe6GOXg/edit#gid=1416330524)

Comment: I'm looking into it, trying to understand fully what you did. It may take me some time and I wanted to thank you before anything else: thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Hey, don't forget to accept this answer if it fulfills your needs :)

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to tinker it with it to make sure I understood your solution. It seems it does, though I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the need to hard write the column targeted by the checkboxes. (In your filter function)

Comment: You can try  `=sequence()` starting at 65 like this : `=ArrayFormula(CHAR(SEQUENCE(5,1, 65)))` or use `CELL("address",A1)` then extract the column